# How to notify when version of package is changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

We have two versions of the package: installed in node_modules and defined in  package.json. After change version and push changes to SCM, other developers should be notified on the build process. How to notify if versions are mismatched? We use webpack for building our application and webpack-notifier for display errors and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You could `dry-run` the `npm install` to list all the dependencies that have to be installed to run with the newest version:

```
echo "The newest version runs with these additional packages:";
npm install --dry-run
```

[docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: It is an additional command for executing before start build project. I know, it is good practice for check dependencies after update branch, but many people did not follow this rule. I try to find how to notify them about changes in packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [check dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-dependencies), and you insert this as a prestart, prebuild, prewatever script, so when dev runs `npm build` this cli is going to run.